# Galvanic corrosion between copper, silver, nickel, and chrome plated brass

Tags: corrosion

My PC uses a custom liquid cooling loop, in the loop currently I have [copper](https://shop.aquacomputer.de/product_info.php?products_id=3371&language=en) (purity not specified by the manufacturer), silver ([Nickel/.925 silver](https://shop.aquacomputer.de/product_info.php?language=en&products_id=3508)) and nickel plated brass [fittings](https://www.ekwb.com/shop/ek-quantum-torque-6-pack-stc-12-16-nickel) (no specifics from the manufacturer here either). The liquid I use is a liquid cooling "optimized" coolant ([safety data sheet](https://www.3dware.ch/files/Shop/Datenblatt/SDS_DP_Ultra_en_2016_04_06.pdf)). 1 year and so far no issues.

I'd like to add a quick connect fitting to the system but it is chrome plated brass (the word chrome is used by the manufacturer support I contacted). With all these somewhat vague information available is there a way to tell if adding chrome to the system could cause galvanic corrosion? I contacted the manufacturer and this is what they told me:

> ... is chrome-plated and can not corrode.  You do not need to be worry as long as you do not use aluminium in the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Good work on getting the coolant SDS! The liquid contains a *corrosion inhibitor* [benzotriazole](https://www.copper.org/publications/pub_list/pdf/a1349.pdf), and ethylene glycol antifreeze. That decreases risk of corrosion.
- Is the new fitting to be *soldered* into the cooler, to be screwed directly into threaded metal, or to be connected *via* non-conductive plastic or rubber tubing?

  - If there is direct metal-to-metal, there is a *quite small* risk of galvanic corrosion at the fitting, which you might see as a greenish stain on the fitting, after some years.
  - If the fitting is to be connected *via* insulating tubing, then there is virtually no risk of galvanic corrosion, if the chrome plating is only on the outside of the part.

Note that there are different alloys of [brass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass) and bronze, and that brass, by itself, contains zinc that may slowly react with water. The life of the valve depends on its composition.

BTW, make sure all coolant lines and the radiator are mounted so that, in the event of a leak for *any* reason (e.g., mouse nibbling), the coolant does not pour onto the working electronic stuff. <sub>*zap*</sub>.

Comment: Thank you for answering, good news then. Only the screw in fittings will have direct contacts with different materials on the screw threads (nickel to nickel plating, nickel to brass/copper and nickel to chrome plating in my case) but those are unlikely to get into the fluid and cause residue somewhere else, otherwise only the coolant will be the "transmitting" medium with PVC soft tubing.